# Little Issue about curl?

Tags: php, html, curl, session-cookies, libcurl

I'm doing a little robot in php that does the login to a site "A.com", then recover the session, save it in my server and then reconnect using this session and get the content of an restricted web page that require login/password.

This form which Will connect with Curl:

```
            <form action="wLoginUser.asp" method="post" name="FormLoginUser" id="FormLoginUser">
                <input type="hidden" name="Page" id="Page" value= "/PasserAnnonce.asp" />

                        <input type="hidden" name="sQueryString" value= "" id="sQueryString" />


                    <table >
                        <tr><td  height="20"></td></tr>
                        <tr  > 
                            <td class="if_label_field"><label id="id_lab_mail">Mail :</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="idMailLogin" name="idMailLogin" size="35" value="fff@gmail.com"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td class="if_label_field"><label id="id_lab_pwd">Mot de passe :</label></td>

                            <td><input type="password"  id="idPasswordLogin" name="idPasswordLogin" size="20" value="78599g056" onkeypress= "KeyDownPasssword(event);"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chk_session_open" id="chk_session_open" value="1" />
                            <span style="color: #CC0000;">Garder ma session ouverte (72h)</span>
                        <br/>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="chk_save_loginpwd" id="chk_save_loginpwd" value="1" checked/>
                            <span style="color: #0066FF;">Se souvenir du mail / passe (15j)</span>
                        <br/><br/>
                        <span >[Décocher si machine partagée]</font>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr><td></td><td height="10"><img style="CURSOR:pointer" onclick="Login_OnClick();" src="/images/b_valider.gif" width="67" height="18" border="0" alt=""/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td  height="20"></td></tr>

                        <tr align="left">
                        <td colspan="2">
                        <span class="info">Vous avez oublié votre mot de passe ?&nbsp;</span>
                        <a href="SendPassword.asp">Cliquez ici</a> 
                        </td></tr>
                    </table>
            </form>
```

this is my full code(works):

```
    $link= 'http://www.tunisie-annonce.com/wLoginUser.asp';  

    $postfields = array(
                  'idMailLogin' => 'XXX@gmail.com',
                  'idPasswordLogin' => 'XXX',
                  'chk_session_open' => 'on',
                  'chk_save_loginpwd' => 'on'
                   );

    $curl = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $link);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);  

    $cookies = __DIR__.'\cookies.txt';

    // For cookies
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);

    $return = curl_exec($curl);  
    curl_close($curl);  

/**************************************************
request 2 : get the content of restrected web page
**************************************************/
  //the restricted web page require login!!
  $lien2 = "http://www.tunisie-annonce.com/PasserAnnonce.asp";   
  $curl = curl_init($lien2);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);


// Read from cookies
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);

$return = curl_exec($curl);
//show restricted web page
echo $return;

curl_close($curl);
```

I tested the code and it works perfectly with the other sites... but exceptionally with this site it does not work(no errors shown )..
My question is :
what is the potential problem that causes this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `curl_getinfo($curl)` after exec to see what response the server gives you.

Comment: The problem is what i make $postfield array(...), the correct whay is $postfield = "var1=val1&var2=val2..";

Answer (score 1):

The link should be

```
$link = 'http://www.tunisie-annonce.com/LoginUser.asp';
```

The form has 2 more hidden fields

```
<input type="hidden" name="Page" id="Page" value="/PasserAnnonce.asp">
<input type="hidden" name="sQueryString" value="" id="sQueryString">
```

Always return what is said, not expected

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_session_open" id="chk_session_open" value="1">
```

Therefore

```
'chk_session_open' => '1',
'chk_save_loginpwd' => '1'
```

The login button has javascript, so check what happens in the function

```
<img style="CURSOR:pointer" onclick="Login_OnClick();" src="/images/b_valider.gif" width="67" height="18" border="0" alt="">
```

So, with these you should check where your problem is from. Note: you should practicall replicate everything they do during there login process.